# What is the use of custom locators in Protractor?

Tags: protractor, elementor

I am new to protractor end to end testing tool. I want to know that,

1. What is the use of custom locators in Protractor?
2. When should we use them?
3. Any Example would be much appreciated?

I have searched in google but nothing more useful found, that can make some understanding about them.

Comment: If you have an element on your website that you have to access by using a combination of other locators or you want to provide optional parameters to the locator, you can wrap it in a custom locator, which is good if you care about `DRY` principle. Example: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator

Answer (score 3):

I use custom locators when I can't use any other locator: id, name, repeater, binding, css etc.

For example I have ngClick attribute and I want to select element using that, this is my code:

```
var customlocators = function() {


by.addLocator('ngClick', function(toState,parentelement) {


     var using = parentelement || document ;
     var prefixes = ['ng-click'];
      for (var p = 0; p < prefixes.length; ++p) {
          var selector = '*[' + prefixes[p] + '="' + toState + '"]';
          var inputs = using.querySelectorAll(selector);
          if (inputs.length) {
              return inputs;
          }
      }     

});
}

module.exports = new customlocators();
```

Then I can use in tests like any other locator:

```
element(by.ngClick('addAuthentication()')).click();
```